# Array Returns Blank Values JavaScript - google.script.run.withSuccessHandler()

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm using Google-Appscripts (JavaScript)

I've a line of code here

`console.log("filldata()"+x);`
`google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(getcolumndata).getcolumncontent(x);`

`getcolumncontent()` is in my Code.gs file and `getcolumndata()` is in my js.html file.

I've a logger.log at the top of `getcolumncontent()` to see the content of `X` once it is passed. `X` in this case is an array with 3 parts, all strings (no dates).

`function getcolumncontent(x){ Logger.log("x ",x); }`

X is returned as a blank and I'm not sure why? if anyone has any suggestions please let me know.

I have an similar line of code 2 line above the issue line THAT WORKS NO PROBLEM - `google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(setcolumndata).getcolumns(y);` where `y` is an array with 2 parts both strings, no dates.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If your problem is that you can't see the content of x in the console log from this piece of code:

```
function getcolumncontent(x){ Logger.log("x ",x); }
```

then I think it's because you haven't concatenated your string. You should have used a + instead of a ,:

```
function getcolumncontent(x){ Logger.log("x " + x); }
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Do you have a return value?

I'm not sure what is in `getcolumncontent()` but whatever is **returned** from that function, is what gets passed to the `onSuccessHandler`.

For example

```js
function one(x){
        x += 1
        return x // this "new" x is passed to the onSuccessHandler
    }
    
function two(x){
        Logger.log(x)
    }
```

```js
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(two).one(1);
```

This will print `2` to the Apps Script console.

#### Referenece

- [Client Server Communications Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication)